# How do I prevent logging a certain route alone in my log files in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I prevent logging a certain route alone in my log files in production environment

```
Started GET "/bar" for 134.45.310.236 at 2014-00-13 06:36:23 +0000
Processing by FooController#index as HTML
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2.6ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Silencer](https://rubygems.org/gems/silencer) Gem

To use it, create an initializer (like config/initializers/silencer.rb) with the contents:

```rb
require 'silencer/rails/logger'

Rails.application.configure do
  config.middleware.swap(
    Rails::Rack::Logger, 
    Silencer::Logger, 
    config.log_tags,
    silence: ["/noisy/action.json"]
  )
end
```

And just add your routes to the silence array